# How can I obtain file meta information in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

I'm looking for a module or some way to obtain the information about the content of a file.

The same sort of thing that the Linux "file" command does, but in Perl language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the File::Magic module on the CPAN. (Editor's note: This module was removed by its author.)

Comment: File::LibMagic describes the pros and cons on the various modules (File::Type is another). I wanted as comprehensive as possible, which sounds like LibMagic.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at File::Magic

http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/File-Magic-0.01/

File::Magic is no longer supported. Use File::MMagic instead (also metacpan.org is now preferred over search.cpan.org)

https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MMagic

Answer (score -1):

I finally opted to do something like

```
$res = `file a.txt`;
```

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable and expeditious approach. However, you are reliant on your system magic file that way.